# kendo ui pager re-style

Tags: listview, kendo-ui, styles, kendo-grid

I want to customize my kendo pager style. The elements that I want in my pager are an combobox with option with the number of items per page (.k-pager-sizes);  the arrows and numbers of pages ('.k-pager-nav and ul.k-pager-numbers') and finally the pager info (.k-pager-info). 
For instance how can I change the order of the elements that are showed in the pager, because by default kendo my combobox after the arrows. Is it possible without workarounds?

I'm using kendo in a Grid and in a ListView. For the Grid I could customize within the databound and using some workarounds

```
$('.k-pager-nav, ul.k-pager-numbers').wrapAll('<div class="pagerContainer"pt/>');
```

then in the css and using flexbox concepts I could change the position the elements appear.

In the listView I could do it in the databound. Just in a general script file. But don't work all the times. Don't know why.  If I clean my history and cache it doesn't run the above script

Working with the databound seems to be a good option but why it's not working. Anyone have ever did this type of re-style of the pager in a ListView? Any examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall, kendo has a strict Dom model/heirarchy when applying its events. If you are experiencing issues with your events, its because kendo can no longer find your pager elements as they are now wrapped inside your custom-named div.  I would suggest that you restyle the pager elements without wrapping it; override the existing CSS classes instead. Good luck.

Comment: I don't think the problem it's about the wrapper element that I create because before that above code I have a console.log that count the number of .k-pager-nav. And it returns zero when should return 4. But even so I will pay attention to this point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With that drastic of a difference (completely different DOM elements) you should really just make a custom widget instead. Since the Kendo code is open source now, you can even copy/paste their pager widget, then derive your own from it.